# failed to open stream wp-settings.php on line 21 fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

Warning: require(/home/*******/public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/******/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/****/public_html/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php55/usr/share/php') in /home/******/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 21

Can't see anything of my site and can't login to wordpress panel
but i can access cpanel
last thing i was do edit RTL.css and i undo my edits

Comment: Try re-uploading all files & folders - except the wp-content folder - from a fresh download of WordPress X.X.

Comment: SETUP fresh wordpress
or just upload files FTP

Answer (score 2):

Try uploading "load.php" in binary transfer mode.

It could be also a permission problem:

- All **directories** should be 755 or 750.
- All **files** should be 644 or 640. Exception: wp-config.php
  should be 440 or 400 to prevent other users on the server from
  reading it.

Comment: Hi @ThomasEthridge can you please describe HOW you solved this issue? Am having a similar problem. Thanks.